# MySQL : able to create a table through MySQL command line, but not able to create via XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I ran the following query in MySQL command line and the tables were created. But when I ran in XAMPP, I got an error "1005 - Can't create table 'zoneboard.work' (errno: 150)"

My query is :

```
Create Table user (
   id_user INT (50)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
   username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
   password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )
) ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE work (
  id_user INT( 50 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  task VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
  comments VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
  assignee VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
  priority VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
  status VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
  dataum1 VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
  dataum2 VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id_user ),
  FOREIGN KEY(assignee) REFERENCES user(username)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
   id_user INT (50)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
   username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
   PASSWORD VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id_user, username ),
  INDEX(username)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Parent table-user should have an index column(Here username should be indexed).
Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

Comment: But I got an error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zoneboard`.`work`, CONSTRAINT `assignee` FOREIGN KEY (`assignee`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`))

Comment: When did you get this error? If you are INSERTing values in child which doesn't match in parent then you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

According to MySQL Documentation : `If you are creating a table, it must have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error message.`

Therefore, try adding an index on your foreign key field `username` as the following:

```
CREATE INDEX username_index ON 'user'(username)
```

Comment: It's true, but index should be put not on assigne (foreing key IS an index) but on a username in the user table!

Comment: I've edited my answer. I was mistaken, thank you for your warning.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the primary key of the user table. Integer is faster and it is more secure to use the primary key instead of a none unique value. Imagine you have 2 or more rows with the same username.

```
CREATE TABLE `work` (
  `id_user` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `assignee` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dataum1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dataum2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
  KEY `assignee` (`assignee`),
  CONSTRAINT `assignee` FOREIGN KEY (`assignee`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: But got an error : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zoneboard`.`work`, CONSTRAINT `assignee` FOREIGN KEY (`assignee`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`))